# Order by with 3 table with same column name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want select my 3 table and have a order by of same column name

e.g:

`table 1: id, name`

`table 2: id, table_1_id, process, datetime`

`table 3: id, table_1_id, process, datetime`

I want to select the table 2 and table 3 with the id of table 1 then order them by datetime. How can I do it in laravel-eloquent? Thanks

Example of what I want to happen.

`id|name |process|datetime
 2 |dina |Making |2019-7-15
 3 |mark |Molding|2019-7-14
 1 |ares |Folding|2019-7-13`

Comment: you can do this by specifying relationshipname and column name like this $query->orderBy('table2.datetime', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('table3.datetime', 'ASC')

Comment: Can you give me the full query? I tried that using join() of the table 2 and table 3 in table 1 but it will only give me a single row result

Comment: why you have used joins you can use eloquent Relationship that will be more usefull

Comment: Sorry but i'm not using eloquent relationship. Is there other way?

Comment: Yaa join is one way but i recommend you to use eloquent relationship

Comment: I tried join but its only giving me a single row result

Comment: `DB::table('table1')->join('table2', 'table2.table1_id', '=', 'table1.id')->join('table3', 'table3.table1_id', '=', 'table1.id')->orderBy('table2.datetime', 'DESC')->orderBy('table3.datetime', 'DESC')->get();` This is what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using union() here is the solution

```
$table2 = DB::table('table1')
           ->join('table2', 'table2.table1_id', '=', 'table1.id')
           ->orderBy('table2.datetime', 'DESC')
           ->select('table1.*', 'table2.*');

$table = DB::table('table1')
          ->join('table3', 'table3.table1_id', '=', 'table1.id')
          ->orderBy('table3.datetime', 'DESC')
          ->select('table1.*', 'table3.*')
          ->union($table2)->get();
```

Thank you all for the help!